# typedef an existing enum type, possible?

Tags: c++, enums, typedef

Given the following:

```
namespace otherns
{
    enum MyEnum_e { MyEnum_YES, MyEnum_NO };
}

namespace myns
{
    typedef otherns::MyEnum_e MyEnum_e;
}
```

Why is the following not valid?

```
int e = myns::MyEnum_YES;
```

I get a compiler error stating:

```
'MyEnum_YES' is not a member of 'myns'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the enum values live in the namespace `otherns`, not as a child of `MyEnum_e`: to reference `MyEnum_YES`, you type `otherns::MyEnum_YES`.

You might try this:

```
namespace otherns
{
    namespace MyEnum_e_space {
    enum MyEnum_e { MyEnum_YES, MyEnum_NO };
    }
    using namespace MyEnum_e_space;
}

namespace myns
{
    using namespace otherns::MyEnum_e_space;
}
```

Although, using `using` is discouraged..

Comment: It's not discouraged, just use it judiciously; the rule of thumb is: not in header files (because you don't want to inflict namespace pollution or even symbol resolution conflicts on any odd future client of the header file). Feel free to use `using` in your own compilation units